# Autowiring static member via components constructor

Tags: java, spring, static, dependency-injection

I know this compiles, but my question is, is it a good idea? I'm mostly curious about why it might NOT be a good idea. Even better, is there an alternative, if `SomeStaticClass` is a `@Component`, but it also must be a static member of `MyComponent`. My understanding is that its poor design to have Spring autowire static members. Based on what I've read, I still don't quite understand why. Say I have the following:

```
@Component
public final class MyComponent {

  private static SomeStaticClass someStaticClass;

  @Autowired
  MyComponent(SomeStaticClass someStaticClass) {
    MyComponent.someStaticClass = someStaticClass;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Few reasons why it's a bad design:

- `static` mutable fields are a bad design in general
- makes testing harder - once this field is set, it will remain set in the next test, possibly creating hidden interdependency
- what if you want to have two instances of `MyComponent`, each with different `SomeStaticClass`? Chaos.
- you cannot inject values via `static` field or setter autowiring, it's explicitly forbidden. There must be a reason for that.
- why do you even need that? Do you have `static` methods in `MyComponent`? Why?
- if the above is true, how do you prevent calling `MyComponent.staticMethod()` before the constructor initialized that field? The whole point of Spring is to return fully populated, safe beans

Answer (score 2):

Spring beans are singletons by default, so make `someStaticClass` an instance field, and keep your code clean and testable. There is no reason for `someStaticClass` to be static. Non-final static fields are a smell.

Answer (score 0):

`@Component` basically means your bean is Singleton by default. So having a static dependency in it does not make much sense. But it will compile as you said.

Answer (score 0):

By default all Spring beans are singleton so no need for `static` here when designing your classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is poor design, because the life cycles are different. Static variable, once initialized will continue to exist even when the application context is closed.

Another mismatch is that there can be more than one application contexts. What if `SomeStaticClass` is a registry? Then this will lead to chaos, as Tomasz pointed out .

Also there is a possibility that the variable will be accessed before the container has been initialized. The chance is greater than you may expect: some bean in the container may call a static method of `MyComponent` during its initialization, while the initialization of `MyComponent` will be performed after(this is because the bean dependencies are implicit in this case, so the IoC container does not know the right order - you'll have to use `@DependsOn` annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Despite of the design flaws, if you need to initialize a static variable with context it should be done as soon as possible.

There are several possibilities, some that are compatible with `@Autowired` are:

- Let class to implement `ApplicationListener` or use an `ApplicationListener` to refresh it.
- Override `onRefresh()` method and refresh it.
- Make the bean definition the first one, singleton are instantiated in the same order that registered.
- Use `depends-on` on on some other early instatiated bean, a MessageSource is a good chance.

Is quite dark, but if you really need it...

Other option is  write a BeanFactoryPostProcessor an inject the static field by hand